# Extracting bits from a 64 bit hex address into an unsigned int in C

Tags: c, caching, bit-manipulation

I am currently working on a program to simulate a cache in C. I have been researching, I know how to set and test individual bits, but how could I extract x amount of bits from within the middle of a 64 bit hex address?

For example, I have a 64 bit hex address. The first 2 bits are dedicated for the block offset, the next 2 bits are dedicated for the set index, and the last 60 for the tag. How could I extract the first 2 bits into an unsigned integer? How could I extract the next 2 bits?

EDIT: This is just an example. I am hoping for a solution that will let you get any amount of bits anywhere in the address

SECOND EDIT: When I say first 2 bits, I mean the least significant bits. My apologies.

Comment: The phrase "first" in "first 2 bits"  is open to interpretation: do you mean the first 2 least significant bits or the first two most significant bits?  Better to use "least significant" or "most significant" rather than "first".  The 2 answers reflect that confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast to [`uintptr_t`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1845491/1111371) from `<stdint.h>` and use `>>` and `&` to extract bits.

E.g.

```
uintptr_t ptr_int = (uintptr_t) ptr;
unsigned int bits1 = (unsigned int)((ptr_int >> 62) & 0x3)  // First two most significant bits
unsigned int bits2 = (unsigned int)((ptr_int >> 60) & 0x3)  // Next two most significant bits
```

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef struct parse64 {
    unsigned int get:2,
    unsigned int set:2,
    unsigned int tag:60 // if your system is a64 bit system
} parse64;
```

In your code:

```
struct parse64 *parser;
parser = (struct parse64 *) data;

unsigned int get = parser->get;
```

based on your edit

> EDIT: This is just an example. I am hoping for a solution that will
>   let you get any amount of bits anywhere in the address

you can get your data with bitwise operation too:

```
get = data & 0x03 //in binary 0X03 is equivalent to 00....000011
set = (data & 0x12)>>2 //in binary 0X12 is equivalent to 00....001100
```

Comment: That might be the correct layout for the bit-fields; it is not guaranteed to be the correct layout.  Actually, very little is guaranteed about bit fields by the standard.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler could you clarify more or give a link for this ( SO topic)

Comment: That would be a good solution, however I need to generalize it for any amount of bits dedicated to tag, set index, etc

Comment: @Tom you cab use bitwise operation. see my answer for details

Comment: Amongst others: [SO 10128044](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10128044/), [SO 18284640](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18284640/), [SO 13105313](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13105313/), [SO 14336994](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14336994/), [SO 1490092](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490092/).